# When two objects are dependent on each other? How to de-couple them?

Tags: javascript, object, decoupling

Bit of a generic question but non the less I am in a situation where I do not know what to do and google has failed me!

I am trying to re-write a grid array collision with canvas that I built.

Now there is a grid object and a block object. The grid `cellSize` is dependent on being the same size of the block `size` and vice versa. The reason being is that to work out the grid array to store the blocks into I must first work out how to build it and that is dependent on the size of the block. Example,

```
var grid = new grid();

function grid() {
    this.cellSize = 50;
    this.cellsX = canvas.width / this.cellSize;
    this.cellsY = canvas.height / this.cellSize;
    this.buildGrid = function() {
        var arr = new Array(this.cellsX);
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            arr[i] = new Array(this.cellsY);
        }
        return arr;
    };
    this.arr = this.buildGrid();
    this.getGridCoords = function(i) {
        return Math.floor(i / this.cellSize);
    };
}

function block() {
    this.size = grid.cellSize; // size of the block is same as cellSize
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0 - (this.size * 1.5);
    this.baseVelocity = 1;
    this.velocity = this.baseVelocity;
    this.update = function() {
        this.y += this.velocity;
    };
}
```

Doing it the way I have done it couples the two objects together and from what I have percieved that is a bad thing. How can I make sure that the two variables are the same size without coupling the objects if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue is that your block() function is taking a value directly from an instance of grid().

If you want your block() function to be reusable and decoupled, its as easy as changing block() to take the size during construction.

```
arr[i] = new block({size: this.cellSize});
```